# How to apply AND operator for values in reference table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table named `Raipur_Restaurant_List` with schema

```
RestID
name
username
password
....
....
....
and some more fields
```

where RestID is the `primary key`

and another table named `Raipur_Restaurant_List_Dine_Types` having schema

```
RestID
Dine_Name
```

where RestID is the `foreign key` referenced to the table Raipur_Restaurant_List

Example data:

Raipur_Restaurant_List:

```
RestID    name          username          password           ....
1001    Demo Name 1   Demo Username 1   Demo Password 1      ....
1002    Demo Name 2   Demo Username 2   Demo Password 2      ....
1003    Demo Name 3   Demo Username 3   Demo Password 3      ....
```

Raipur_Restaurant_List_Dine_Types:

```
RestID      Dine_Name
 1001       HomeDelivery
 1002       Bakeries
 1001       Bakeries
```

How can I get the restaurants that have Dine_Name of both HomeDelivery and Bakeries?

I tried the following code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (RRL.RestID)
              , RRL.Username
              , RRL.openAir
              , RRL.Name
              , RRL.Address
              , RRL.thumbnailBckImg
              , RRL.Fixed_Disc
              , RRL.rating
              , RRL.searched 
           FROM Raipur_Restaurant_List AS RRL 
           JOIN Raipur_Restaurant_List_Dine_Types AS RRLDT 
             ON RRL.RestID = RRLDT.RestID 
          WHERE RRLDT.Dine_Name = 'DineIN' 
            AND RRLDT.Dine_Name = 'Bakeries'
          LIMIT 0,200
```

but it's not fetching the required rows.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a FUNCTION, and LIMIT without ORDER BY is (fairly) meaningless

Comment: SELECT ... WHERE ... IN ('a','b') GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT([DISTINCT] ...) = x [where x = the number of arguments in IN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it

```
SELECT DISTINCT RRL.RestID, RRL.Username, RRL.openAir, RRL.Name, RRL.Address, RRL.thumbnailBckImg, RRL.Fixed_Disc, RRL.rating, RRL.searched 
FROM Raipur_Restaurant_List AS RRL 
JOIN Raipur_Restaurant_List_Dine_Types AS RRLDT ON RRL.RestID = RRLDT.RestID 
WHERE RRLDT.Dine_Name IN ('HomeDelivery','Bakeries') 
LIMIT 0 , 200;
```

If you need alteast 2 count have then try below-

```
SELECT DISTINCT RRL.RestID, RRL.Username, RRL.openAir, RRL.Name, RRL.Address, RRL.thumbnailBckImg, RRL.Fixed_Disc, RRL.rating, RRL.searched 
FROM Raipur_Restaurant_List AS RRL 
JOIN Raipur_Restaurant_List_Dine_Types AS RRLDT ON RRL.RestID = RRLDT.RestID 
WHERE RRLDT.Dine_Name IN ('HomeDelivery','Bakeries') 
having count(distinct RRLDT.Dine_Name)>1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `having` clause to limit the result to those rows that matches both types:

```
SELECT  
  RRL.RestID, RRL.Username, RRL.Name    
FROM Raipur_Restaurant_List AS RRL 
JOIN Raipur_Restaurant_List_Dine_Types AS RRLDT 
  ON RRL.RestID = RRLDT.RestID 
WHERE RRLDT.Dine_Name IN ('HomeDelivery', 'Bakeries')
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

The last line can be more explicit: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT RRLDT.Dine_Name) = 2;` although applying distinct to the count might affect performance - I'm not sure about this though.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b490/1)

A version that returns all rows for the matches:

```
SELECT RRL.RestID, RRL.Username, RRL.Name, RRLDT.Dine_Name
FROM Raipur_Restaurant_List AS RRL 
JOIN Raipur_Restaurant_List_Dine_Types AS RRLDT 
  ON RRL.RestID = RRLDT.RestID 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Raipur_Restaurant_List_Dine_Types 
    WHERE Dine_Name IN ('HomeDelivery', 'Bakeries')
    AND RestID = RRL.RestID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Dine_Name) = 2
)
```

And a sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a6c0/8) for the second version.

Comment: even using the HAVING clause, its resulting like the OR operator in this case, and giving me the data which are either one of them, but i want here data which are both of them (HomeDelivery and Bakeries)

Comment: No, i had just edited in your created fiddle only - [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b490/3)

Comment: You can look my result's screenshot [here](http://i60.tinypic.com/2iaq5o7.png) -- After 4th row, all are only having HomeDelivery and not Bakeries and their Dine_Name

Comment: update for my comment - [Using having clause](http://tinypic.com/r/29vndwp/8) - Using having clause i am getting only one row, which is not required for my task, sorry for previous comment's mistake

Comment: it should be two rows per Dine_Name for each RestID where both Dine_Name is HomeDelivery and Bakeries - I had asked for this only in the question

Comment: @AmanSingh Just a bit curious as to why you unaccepted my answer in favor for one that does the same thing as my original answer that you previously claimed didn't work? I fail to see the reason.

Comment: @AmanSingh Also, why did you ask the same question again and accept an identical answer then...

Comment: reason behind asking again was to learn the concept behind it, and there is a bit difference in another post's answer by using group by clause which exactly gave me the result i wanted and i am sorry about unaccepting your answer, it was because you gave the right answer but using sub queries, which seems a bit unefficient in my case as i have generate those queries on the go (dynamically), btw thank you so much for all your effort

Comment: @AmanSingh Thanks for helping me understand the reason. No hard feelings :)